# KDevelop won't start debugging

Tags: debugging, gdb, kdevelop

I used to be able to debug my program but now all of a sudden the debugger won't get past loading libc - or so it would seem.

The debugger breaks with a backtrace pointing to `#0 __libc_read() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:27`

When I then continue the debugger nothing happens. If I try to interrupt nothing happens. I can only Stop debugging.

There is no Debug output and the GDB tool view also contains no info.

When I execute gdb from the command line it works.

OS: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon;
Kdevelop 5.2.1

Here's the full backtrace copied from Kdevelop:

```
#0 __libc_read() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:27
#1 open_verify() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/dl-load.c:1686
#2 _dl_map_object() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/dl-load.c:2327
#3 map_doit() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:591
#4 _dl_catch_exception() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#5 _dl_catch_error() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#6 do_preload() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:762
#7 handle_ld_preload() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:860
#8 dl_main() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:1618
#9 _dl_sysdep_start() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/dl-sysdep.c:253
#10 _dl_start_final() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:414
#11 _dl_start() at /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/rtld.c:521
#12 _start() at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#13 ??() at 
#14 ??() at 
#15 ??() at 
#16 ??() at 
#17 ??() at 
#18 ??() at 
#19 ??() at 
#20 ??() at 
#21 ??() at
```

Comment: Please try with the latest AppImage from https://www.kdevelop.org/download

Comment: I tried that version and at first it didn't work. Then I tried debugging and I noticed the tab [Breakpoints] in the bottom and there I did right click>Remove all. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: So now it's ok?

Comment: Yes. I can use the debugger again.